# conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class after proguard obfuscation

Tags: spring, obfuscation, proguard

after Proguard obfuscation i get the following error :

> Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation-specified bean name 'a'
>   for bean class [com.company.project.b.a.a.a] conflicts with existing,
>   non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
>   [com.company.project.a.a]

i'm using annotation based spring configuration , how can i avoid having two classes with the same name using Proguard because Spring doesn't allow two beans to have the same name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can specify bean name in @Component (and stereotypes @Repository, @Service and @Controller) value:

```
@Component("myBeanName")
public class MyBean {

}
```

Comment: Even i faced similar probem.. I already have a fully functional working code. And in most of the classes only annotations are used without specifying the bean name. Now its highly impossible to go to every code and start giving the bean name. Can you please suggest any alternatives?

Comment: ProGuard has an option `-useuniqueclassmembernames` which prevents generation of two classes with same name in different packages. But this doesn't solve everything. It will fail if you try to get a bean by name programmatically, or if it's referenced in an XML (like OP) or annotation, and many more cases. There's another option `-keepnames` to specify which classes and their members must not change its name. Useful, but use it carefully if you want to keep a really obfuscated code.

Comment: And I think we should use @Qualifier("BeanName") when we are declaring them with @Autowire annotation. I solved my problems in this way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and nothing else was helping out. Sometimes the problem occurs if you have moved your classes around and it refers to old classes, even if they don't exist.

In this case, just do this :

```
mvn eclipse:clean

mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause; you may have different versions of Spring in your classpath, for example, spring 2.x with spring 3.x. In such condition, beans seem to be loaded twice. If you use maven, check if a module does not import an old version of Spring (mvn dependency:tree) and remove it by excluding the involved spring artifact (exclusions).